# Console.log returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this not working?

```
var names;

$.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : postUrl+"/admin/returnUserJSON",
     success : function(data){
          names = data;
     }
});

console.log(names);
```

**Problem:** Console.log is returning undefined.

Comment: Put the `console.log(names);` inside the `success` callback. Remember:  AJAX stands for [**Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O)

Comment: just make sure that success is being called..

Comment: This type of question is asked at least five times a week.

Comment: @ahren: I'd say three times a day :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `$.ajax` call is asynchronous, the `console.log` will be called *before* `names=data` line will be executed (as it's a part of `$.ajax` callback function, which will be called only after the server's response). Hence it will output `undefined`.

You can fix it two ways: either move your output into the callback function...

```
function(data){
  names = data;
  console.log(names);
}
```

... or make use of Promise interface:

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : postUrl+"/admin/returnUserJSON",
     success : function(data){
          names = data;
     }
}).then(function() { console.log(names); });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your console.log into the `success` handler.

```
 success : function(data){
      names = data;
      console.log(names);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your AJAX request has not finished firing by the time `console.log` is being executed.

If you move the `console.log` to the `success` callback, you will get the data correctly.

```
var names;

$.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : postUrl+"/admin/returnUserJSON",
     success : function(data){
          names = data;
          console.log(names);
     } 
});
```

I would suggest reading up on [asynchronous javascript programming](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/)!

Answer (score 1):

AJAX request fires after the page has already been loaded, so that's why you get the error. When you print the variable to the console, the variable does not exists.