# Variable scope in Javascript and Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new in javascript, and found some issue with scope of the object/variable,
I need your help to point out why my {endtoken:this.token} is blank, while console.log({rawToken:e.data}) is don't?

I found that understanding the scope of the variable bit confusing in JS compared to Python,
Is there any good easy to read link to understand the concept?

My goal is to get all data from windows parent and Rest API when the component is created.

```
    var obj = {
        token: '',
        init: {},
        user: {}, 
        objInfo: {}
    }; 

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app-4',
    data: obj, 
    created: function(){
        postRobot
        .send(window.parent, "loadingCall", false, {domain: domain})
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });

        postRobot
        .send(window.parent, "tokenCall", {}, { domain: domain })
        .then(function (e) {
            this.token = e.data; // token 
            console.log({rawToken:e.data});
            console.log({token:this.token});
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });

        postRobot
        .send(window.parent, "initCall", {}, { domain: domain })
        .then((e)=>{
            this.init = e.data;
            console.log({rawInit:e.data});
            console.log({init:this.init});
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e.data);
        });

        console.log({endtoken:this.token}); // blank token
        console.log({endinit:this.init}); // blank object
    }
});
```

Regards,

Harris, 10th Grade GPS Jakarta

Comment: Because you try to access it before it becomes available. "then" should be understood literally, it designates that it's called sometime in future when a promised result is available. Also this is a mistake, `.then(function (e) { this.token = e.data;`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0):

this happens due to the asynchronous nature of javascript.
you can read a good article about it [right here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff)

What happens in your code is that your last `console.log` statements (last ones in the file) are get executed before the `then` parts are.

what happens is:

1. you are sending a request through your `postRobot`, (you don't know when the request will return an answer)
2. you are "skipping" the `then` and `catch` parts and run the "last" `console.log`s
3. you get your responses back and only when the response comes back, the `then` part gets executed

basically you are logging the data before it has arrived and was set in these variables and therefore the output of the log is the data initial state

[this post has a similar case as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021200/console-log-returning-undefined)